# Change "header files" (folder name) from Chinese to English in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, header-files

Hi completely vs and c++ beginner here.

The project was made in a "chinese working environment", thus you can see the "header files, source files, and resource files" are all in chinese after I loaded it in my "english working environment". Is there any way I can make them English? Or I can just manually change them?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Either within the IDE*: right-click each folder name, select Rename from the context menu, and enter any name you prefer, including the default English name.

*Or outside the IDE*: close the project in Visual Studio, edit the `.vcxproj.filters` file in the project root (using a UTF-8 aware text editor), and replace the `...` on the `<Filter Include="...">` lines with the names you want.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did exactly the first way and the project just built fine :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you could try the following steps:

1,Open up Visual Studio Installer.

2,Click on the modify button.

3,Under the language packages tab you'll see English there, check the box and download it.
[image]

4,And than at Visual Studio toolbar just click **Tools --> Options --> Environment --> International Settings --> English.**

[image]